# Permissions on Application Folder

Tags: c#, permissions, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I have a default application setup created using Visual Studio 2005. When my application is installed, it's only work running as administrator, because some files are written in the Application Folder.

I have found that on Visual Studio 2010 there is a property for change this permission on some folders inside application folder.

How can I allow to my application create and edit specific files inside the application folder without run it as admin?

Comment: However I would advise to change the location of application data: Microsoft guidelines were to not write files to Program Files, *always* but nobody cared until they removed administrative privileges from Administrators using UAC which broke many application that assumed everyone is administrator. This assumption has always been false.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov thanks for advice. I already know that, but it's complicated change everything in a legacy code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are your options, assuming that you cannot change where the application itself attempts to read/write files:

- Change the default installation directory of the installer of the application, to not go inside C:\ProgramFiles, but instead to a folder just off the C:\ drive that has more lax access permissions. This was standard practice in Windows 3.1 and even Windows 95, but these days you can't get a program "certified" by Microsoft as compatible with any supported Windows version unless it installs into the proper Program Files directory. These modern OSes also have the root of the C:\ drive locked down pretty tight so you'd need administrative permissions to install the app (but not to run it).
- Create a custom action for the installer which increases the access rights of the program subfolder during installation. Again, Microsoft is unlikely to certify the app if you do this, and this also requires admin permissions to install the app, meaning the average user on your network can't just pull it down and run it.
- Install the files that must be altered in the "proper" places (Application Data for user-specific files, Program Data for files pertaining to the software as a whole), and then create shortcuts within the main application folder that point to the files in their accessible locations. The legacy app shouldn't know the difference.

**EDIT:** Here's a method straight out of the custom actions of the installer for an app I wrote that has a similar "legacy" app, which has to read/write data from config files in a subfolder of the app's "home" directory. The IDictionary passed in is the one you get from the various custom action methods (OnBeforeInstall, OnAfterInstall, OnCommit, etc), so you simply drop this into an Installer class, call it from the handler for the install event of your choice (which must be after the installer has made the file system changes), and call it:

```
private void SetEditablePermissionOnConfigFilesFolder(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        if (!Context.Parameters.ContainsKey("installpath")) return;

        //Get the "home" directory of the application
        var path = Path.GetFullPath(Context.Parameters["installpath"]);

        //in my case the necessary files are under a ConfigFiles folder;
        //you can do something similar with individual files
        path = Path.Combine(path, "ConfigFiles");
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        var accessControl = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

        //Give every user of the local machine rights to modify all files
        //and subfolders in the directory
        var userGroup = new NTAccount("BUILTIN\\Users");
        var userIdentityReference = userGroup.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

        accessControl.SetAccessRule(
            new FileSystemAccessRule(userIdentityReference,
                                     FileSystemRights.Modify,
                                     InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit 
                                        | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                     PropagationFlags.None,
                                     AccessControlType.Allow));
        //Commit the changes.
        dirInfo.SetAccessControl(accessControl);
    }
```

Comment: About the second option. Do you know how to change theses permissions?

Comment: Yeah, gimme a sec to find and sanitize some code I've used to do this for one of my in-house apps.

Comment: This code is for a specific file. If i run it for a folder, I should make any change?

Comment: This code is actually for a folder, not a file, so the only change necessary is to point it at the folder applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write anything to the application folder (under program files). Instead use the user's home folder, or, if you want to write something that's relevant to all users on the machine - ProgramData.

EDIT:

If you can't change your application code, you should still avoid placing program data files under ProgramFiles if you can. There's one other thing you can do. You can create a folder under c:\ProgramData, and just create a symbolic link to it from C:\Program Files... . That way, your legacy application still finds the data where it expects to find it.

Comment: I know it should be done in this way. But it's some lagacy code, and I cannot change quickly.

Comment: `You should avoid`, the problem is: I will not install my software! Sorry but you buy a program and you install wherever you want! See the @KeithS anwser, it's solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could manually change the NTFS folder permissions using Windows Explorer to the Application Folder. However, it would be best practice to read/write to a different folder.

Comment: I know it should be done in this way. But it's some lagacy code, and I cannot change quickly.

Comment: If you are confident the program will not alter any application critical files you could assign Modify NTFS permission to Everyone on the Application Folder.

Comment: how can I do that using application setup? There is a command line I can execute as Custom Action?

Comment: What is the path to your Application Folder i.e. C:\Program Files\...?

Comment: Yes. Something as: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\App`

Comment: Very easy to do via GUI, Right Click Folder > Properties > Security Tab > Edit... > Check Allow Modify Checkbox (for Everyone group) > OK > OK

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that on GUI. But I believe that is not a good idea add this advertise on a Install Guide. I need a automatic install. The user should only execute the install and everything works fine!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18117/discussion-between-victor-and-mike)